# Calling a jQuery method named in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript variable which contains the name of a jQuery method:

```
var method = 'attr("src")';
```

How can I make it work like:

```
console.log($('img').method)
```

I tried

```
console.log($('img')[method]())
```

but it gives this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'attr("src")'
```

Comment: You are about to do something very, very eval. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp I need to go wash.

Comment: Ha!  Eval!  I get it!

Comment: Why are you doing this, instead of setting `method` to a function?

Comment: It's going to be difficult with `eval` as well, since you need to combine it with the jQuery object.

Comment: `method` in your example is not a function, but a call of function with parameter. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Shtirlits You should probably explain your overall issue instead of this very specific question.  As you have it constrained at the moment, you almost certainly require `eval`, which you really want to avoid.  If you explain more of what you are trying to do overall, someone can likely offer a better overall suggestion to avoid `eval`.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Indeed. If evil() is your only solution, you're asking the wrong questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue you have is that you have both the method name *and* its parameters encoded in a single string.

If instead you had an *array* containing first the method name and then the parameters, this would be easy, per the following trivial plugin I just knocked together:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.invoke = function(args) {
        var method = args.shift();
        return $.fn[method].apply(this, args);
    }
})(jQuery);

var method = ['attr', 'src'];
var src = $('img').invoke(method);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/7rBDe/1/

Comment: This is certainly the way to go

Comment: +1 for attempting to rationalise an answer. Probably the case though, that it simply needs to be rethought from the ground up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function fun(funcName){
  return $('img')[funcName]('src');
}

fun('attr');
```

This is a pretty simple approach but it works ,because `$('img').attr('src')` is same if you wrote this `$('img')['attr']('src')`

Comment: Would anyone mind telling me `why the downvoting` ,let me know I will improve my answer !

Comment: to improve this answer, first remove all reference to `eval()`  ;-)

Comment: @Alnitak thanx for the input ,I have improved my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use new function too, not same scope than eval:

```
(new Function( "return $('img')."+method )())
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J9zU4/

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing as `method` is actually a combination of a method and a parameter.  If you can break things up into just the method name and just the parameter you can do something like this:

```
var method = 'attr';
var param = 'class';
$('.post-text')[method](param);  // returns "post-text" on this page.
```

Which is the same thing as:

```
$('post-text').attr('class');
```